# Active Screen Reader

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, warnings, screen-readers

Every time I open a new folder or restart my laptop I see an "**Screen Reader Detected**" warning in my terminal window.

[image: terminal error]

I have also tried turning "off" the *accessibility Support* in the terminal setting, but still no luck.

[image: settings]

Is there any way to solve this problem. Or maybe a way to detect the screen reader so that I can turn it off.

*Note*: I have not installed any external screen readers. I also have turned "off" the "Narrator" in my windows 10 machine.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the `terminal error` and ran `Install-Module PSReadLine`?

Comment: Yes I did, & it works fine too. But again after reopening Visual Studio Code I get the same warning.

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if you have any accessability tools installed on your device like NVDA (non-visual desktop access), and also some web dev suites as they will often include accessibility assessment tools.

These tools will toggle a registry value that can 'light up' accessibility features on apps that are designed with this in mind.

The specific key to check is here, which you can navigate to with `regedit.exe`:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access
```

if you have the Key `On` with a value of `1`, then this will trigger the warning.

To remove the warning, simply set the key to 0.  You can do this with PowerShell or the old school `reg` command.

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\Blind Access" /V On /d 0
```

Source: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11751